# Disabled hangfire recurring job keeps executing

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, hangfire

I've defined a recurring job like this because I want to run it manually on demand from the dashboard one time only:

```
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(() => _service.StartDev(), Cron.Never);
```

It appears correctly as disabled in the dashboard:

[image]

The problem is that after I've executed it once it keeps executing again and again, that's how it looks in the database:

[image]

**Question:** how can I prevent such behavior and make it to be executed only once on demand?

I've tried putting those attributes on the interface (and function before), but they don't do the job

```
[DisableConcurrentExecution(60*120)]
[AutomaticRetry(Attempts = 0, OnAttemptsExceeded = AttemptsExceededAction.Delete)]
```

Comment: I tried same thing but it worked for me. is your job failing ?

Comment: @CodingMytra no, as you see they are all in processing state in the database so I'm also wondering why

Comment: is it _service.StartDev() some long running task

Comment: yes, it is. It runs more than an hour

Comment: and what do you see on dashboard in job tab for processing jobs. does it show that many processing jobs.